# Why does my box keep sending reverse DNS queries and how to stop it?

Tags: reverse-dns

## Situation

My box keeps sending reverse DNS queries about our LAN hosts. Obviously they all fail because they are private addresses.

***Request***

- Source: `192.168.1.6`
- Destination: `192.168.1.1` (default gateway)
- Query: `Standard query 0x2515 PTR 5.1.168.192.in.addr.arpa`

The queries extend to all hosts it finds on the `192.168.1.0/24` network, not only host `192.168.1.5` above.

***Response***

`Standard query response 0x2515 No such name`

## Some Information

(I wanted to paste a screenshot of the pcap file packet capture, but I do not have enough reputations.)

1. Output of `uname -a`:

   `Linux backbox 3.13.0-44-generic #73-Ubuntu SMP Tue Dec 16 00:22:43 UTC 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`
2. I tried to look at `sudo netstat -tunpl` to see if the source ports would be listed there, but I believe because they are UDP, I was not fast enough to catch it on the terminal.
3. I tried searching for a problem like this in DuckDuckGo, but I believe because English is my second language, I might be missing some search terms.
4. The box is a [BackBox](http://www.backbox.org/) distribution. Interestingly I have another box, built from the same BackBox ISO file, but that other box does not behave in the same manner as to perform failed reverse DNS look-ups of our LAN hosts.

## Questions:

1. Why is this happening?
2. How could I find out what is causing the queries?
3. How to stop it?

If anyone could be kind enough to provide a pointer, I shall be very grateful, and reckon I should be able to take from there.

Comment: Note that private addresses failing a reverse DNS lookup is not a given. We have PTR records hosted internally for a majority of our private IPs, even the ones handed out via DHCP, since it is possible to dynamically update PTR records (as well as A records).

Comment: `The source ports for these DNS queries vary` - Of course it does. `1.Why is this happening?` - My guess, based on the fact that the machine is running BackBox, is that it's using rDNS queries as part of it's **Intelligence Gathering** process.

Comment: @joeqwerty - it might the IG process, but I wonder why the other machine I have, which built from the exact same source does not do this.